# UIImage strechable image to generate message bubble-like result

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm trying to implement an strechable image that resembles a dialog bubble however I'm not getting it right,

with the following code:

UIImage *ballon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"strech.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 11, 12, 9)];

I'm getting the following result:

[image]
this is my original leftBubble.png

[image]

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment on jhilgert00's answer, but I'd like to add something: `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]` *tiles* the inner pixels, rather than *stretching*, which is why the gradient doesn't work, as jhilgert00 said.

If you're working with iOS 6.0 or higher, you can use `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:capInsets resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]`

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> -(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
>
> [The] pixel area not covered by the cap in each direction is tiled,
> left-to-right and top-to-bottom, to resize the image.

and

> -(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode
>
> You should only call this method in place of its counterpart if you specifically want your image to be resized with the UIImageResizingModeStretch resizing mode.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have gradient on the entire image. That's where the lines are coming from. The center of you image (the part that gets stretched, needs to be a solid color since it's getting repeated, not only horizontally, but vertically as well.

If you were only stretching the image horizontally, your image miay have worked just fine.

Try this image I made for you, and use some different capInsets:

[image]

```
UIImage *ballon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"strech.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 20, 22, 12)];
```

Notice all of my styling happens on the edge of the bubble, and the center is solid.

EDIT:

Here's a smaller version of the image. I made the larger one so you could see what I was doing.

[image]